# How to use wowza media server in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, rtmp, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, wowza

I have a website in asp.net where i want users to connect their web cam and allow them to broadcast their audio/video.
On other page i want to show their live streaming.

I want to be able to send video stream from my application to a wowza media server.
Is it possible? If yes, then how can i interact with streaming data with my .net application like; if i want to store text chat or take screenshots from the broadcast or want to merge my application data into the chat, what API/Methods should i call from my .net website?

I have seen http://www.wowza.com/media-server/developers#wowza-ide and found that it's for java developer but what about others like .net? Can we use wowza in .net application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not your exact requirement, the Wowza chat tutorial get you headed in the right direction: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?42.

The wowza link describes an example chat client at /examples/VideoChat/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html.  In order to develop your own chat client you'll need to create your own Flash client, typically using ActionScript.  If you aren't a flash developer you could look at [OpenTok](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api) as an alternative to Wowza.  They have a javascript API, no flash development skills required.

Comment: Thanks, i am able to broadcast the video but i want to interact with chat options like, if i want to store text chat or take screenshots from the broadcast or want to merge my application data into the chat, what API/Methods should i call from my .net website?